How to use entity view with Querydsl integration?
The [Querydsl integration]The Querydsl integration describes that "BlazeJPAQuery can be serialized using the JPQLNextSerializer, and may be rendered to a CriteriaBuilder using the BlazeCriteriaBuilderRenderer".
I think that I could use entity view to project JPAQuery if I have a CriteriaBuilder. But there is no detailed description in the documentation about how to code it. I googled the internet and find no answer about it either.
I guess that I could do something like the following, but cannot do it successfully.
BlazeJPAQuery<Cat> query = ...
CriteriaBuilder<Cat> cb = .....(transform the query to a CriteriaBuilder instance)
// then create a new CriteriaBuilder for the entity view from cb
CriteriaBuilder<CatSimpleView> viewBuilder = evm.applySetting(EntityViewSetting.create(CatSimpleView.class), cb);
...

How could I tranform BlazeJPAQuery to CriteriaBuilder?
Thanks for your help very much!

Let's continue with your question on the GitHub issue you created: https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence/issues/1943
